# async="async" attribute of a <script> tag in html, What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, html

`async="async"` attribute of a `<script>` tag in HTML, What does it mean?

```
<script async="async" src="...."></script>
```

Can be see used [here](http://samaxes-demos.appspot.com/samaxesjs/toc-jquery.html) for example

Comment: [YT](https://youtu.be/4sBfx3ISBdM)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If the async attribute is set on an external script (one with src=), browsers that support it will download that script in the background without blocking the rest of the content on the page.  The script will execute whenever it is finished downloading.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-script-async

As I mentioned in a comment, setting async=true, async=false or async=anything all mean the same thing.  They enable the async behavior.  The only way to make a script non-async is to completely omit the attribute.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: So I don't need to place javascript at the bottom of the page if I remember to make it `async`, right?

Comment: First link's anchor doesn't work anymore and there's no mention of `async` on the document.

Answer (score 21):

In XHTML it is needed to consequently note attributes as attributes and their values whereas HTML does not. I like the conformity of that principle so I always use it in the form of:

```
async="async"
```

This way I can serve my documents as application/xhtml+xml.

If this is not of any interest for you because you are of the opinion that serving your document as text/html is good enough, then you can always use:

```
async
```

Comment: Your answer is informative (about doc/mime types) but it did not address my actual question: what the attribute `async` does?

Comment: I am sorry that I was not on topic.

Comment: Async is a new HTML5 attribute for the script element. It causes the browser to continue parsing the rest of the page when it finds a script tag instead of parsing the script first and then continue parsing the page.

I found an interesting tutorial about this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHSeGURldw8

Answer (score 4):

It simply means

1. **Download** the **External Script asyncronously ( or in parallel )** without blocking the html parsing.
2. The **Script once downloaded** will be **Executed Immediately** blocking the html parsing.

[Here's](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html#script-async) a nice illustration.

**Note :** This attribute works only for the external scripts ( the one's with the src attribute ) and not inline scripts.

Answer (score 4):

The [HTML WHATWG specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) contains [the following explanation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-script-async):

> For [classic scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#classic-script), if the [`async`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-script-async) attribute is present, then the
>   classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as
>   soon as it is available (potentially before parsing completes). If the
>   `async` attribute is not present but the `defer` attribute is present,
>   then the classic script will be fetched in parallel and evaluated when
>   the page has finished parsing. If neither attribute is present, then
>   the script is fetched and evaluated immediately, blocking parsing
>   until these are both complete.
>
> For [module scripts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#module-script), if the `async` attribute is present, then the module
>   script and all its dependencies will be fetched in parallel to
>   parsing, and the module script will be evaluated as soon as it is
>   available (potentially before parsing completes). Otherwise, the
>   module script and its dependencies will be fetched in parallel to
>   parsing and evaluated when the page has finished parsing. (The `defer`
>   attribute has no effect on module scripts.)
>
> This is all summarized in the following schematic diagram:

[image]

> The exact processing details for these attributes are, for mostly historical reasons, somewhat non-trivial, involving a number of aspects of HTML. The implementation requirements are therefore by necessity scattered throughout the specification. The algorithms [described in the HTML specification] describe the core of this processing, but these algorithms reference and are referenced by the parsing rules for script start and end tags in HTML, in foreign content, and in XML, the rules for the document.write() method, the handling of scripting, etc.
>
> The `defer` attribute may be specified even if the `async` attribute is specified, to cause legacy Web browsers that only support `defer` (and not `async`) to fall back to the `defer` behavior instead of the blocking behavior that is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Seems it doesn't need to be `async=async` either, but just `async`

From google:

> A second technique is to use the  attribute where
>   appropriate, which prevents parsing from blocking the initial page
>   load by deferring it until the browser's UI thread is not busy doing
>   something else.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/mobile#DeferParsingJS

Answer (score 1):

Just async in enough.

You may try both and then measure the difference in page speed. Like [crictime](http://www.helpnetmat.es/sports/2014/03/crictime-com-live-streaming.html) uses single substance for that.

Comment: No, it is not in all cases.

Comment: In the case of XHTML, served as application/xml+xhtml it is a fatal error and causes the page to freeze when you note an attribute like that.